# Read data attributes from Froala editor

Tags: javascript, html, froala

I am wordking on a custom toolbar button for Froala. In order to perform my action i need to read a data attribute from the original textarea.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('saveAction', {
  title: 'Save action title',
  focus: true,
  undo: false,
  refreshAfterCallback: false,
  callback: function () {
    console.log($(this).data('save-id'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can duplicate text you input. The 2nd textarea is hidden and filled data by event "froalaEditor.keyup"